# javascript delay in a for loop

Tags: javascript

I can't seem to figure out how to add a delay in a javascript for loop. I am looping over emails, for each emails I am sending it to the backend that will actually send the email newsletter. In order not to send too fast, I want to introduce a pause in the for loop. From console.log it can verify that the `delay` method is called AFTER execution of the entire for loop. I have Googled around this topic, but I am not sure I understand the proposed solutions some related to using the `let` and others related to blocking. I am new to javascript, and therefore not fully sure that I understand WHY `delay` is called at the end of the for loop.

```
async sendNewsletter (event) {
       
        //Loop over each email and gather the html content followed by sending it to backend
        let counter = 0
        for (const option of this.includedEmailList.options) {
          

            //Call the backend 
            const response = await fetch('url',
            {
                method:'POST',
                credentials:'same-origin',
                headers:{
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Accept' : 'application/json',
                },
                redirect: 'follow',
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    'emailSubject' : this.emailSubject.value,
                    'email' : option.value,
                    'plainTextEmail' : this.emailPlainText.value,
                    'htmlEmail' : this.hiddenHTML.innerHTML}),
            });  

            const responseJson = await response.json();
            console.log(responseJson['status']);
            this.emailSentStatus.innerHTML = responseJson['status'];

            //I need to delay the loop
            counter++;
            this.delay(10000 * counter);
        }
        //Everything has been sent. Leave a message and disable the submission button to prevent 

        emailSentStatus.innerHTML = `all emails have been sent!`;
    }

delay (timeMilliseconds) {
        //To be used in for loop to delay the loop and to slow down
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('in delay');
            console.log(timeMilliseconds);}, timeMilliseconds);
    }
```

Comment: The `setTimeout()` function schedules something to be run in the future. It does not "delay" code execution, a thing you really can't do in JavaScript. Use the timeout feature to space your requests out as much as you need by using a series of millisecond values, each one further in the future.

Comment: @Pointy: Or have each request schedule when the next request can be processed.

Comment: @ScottHunter sure, whatever makes sense for the application.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean that the setTimeout should actually contain my "send email to backend" code part? Which means that I allow the for loop to run to the end regardless how long time it takes. I don't put the "send email to backend" code in the actual for loop, but put it in the setTimeout code block?

Comment: make a simple queue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand it much better now thanks to Pointy's comment pointing out that it is a scheduler. My understanding initially was trying to delay the for loop, in stead of creating many tasks with the `setTimeout` method each with an increasing delay. The code snippet below work as expected.

```
async submitNewsletterToBackend(emailSubject, emailTo, plainText, htmlMessage) {
        //Call the backend 
        const response = await fetch('url',
        {
            method:'POST',
            credentials:'same-origin',
            headers:{
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept' : 'application/json',
            },
            redirect: 'follow',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                'emailSubject' : emailSubject,
                'email' : emailTo,
                'plainTextEmail' : plainText,
                'htmlEmail' : htmlMessage}),
        });  

        const responseJson = await response.json();
        console.log(responseJson['status']);
        this.emailSentStatus.innerHTML = responseJson['status'];
    }

    sendNewsletter (event) {
        if (this.includedEmailList.options.length === 0) {
            return
        }

        let counter = 0
        for (const option of this.includedEmailList.options) {
            
            counter++;
            setTimeout(this.submitNewsletterToBackend, counter * 100, 
                this.emailSubject.value,
                option.value,
                this.emailPlainText.value,
                this.hiddenHTML.innerHTML
                )
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
delay (timeMilliseconds) {
return new Promise (r => 
        //To be used in for loop to delay the loop and to slow down
        setTimeout(() => {
            r()
            console.log('in delay');
            console.log(timeMilliseconds);}, timeMilliseconds);
})
    }
```

```
await this.delay(10000);
```

Comment: what is r() in your code?

Comment: A function that resolves the promise